# История просмотров. Как ее удалять?

Tags: php, javascript

Как в php автоматически удалять историю просмотров (посещений веб-страниц) с браузера. Возможно, есть решение?
Или даже запретить браузеру сохранять ее.

Comment: Никак. У php нет доступа к истории браузера. И слава богу.

Comment: а javascript?
Или подскажите тогда решение другое есть:
Мне нужно что бы когда жму стрелку назад, то страничка обновлялась, а не загружала старую информацию.

Comment: Назовите хотя бы одну причину, по которой это нужно?

Comment: @zaryad68gmail History API и всё будет так как вы хотите. Но  придется много читать и  мало писать Ж)